# c understanding struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, embedded

Could anybody explain what the line `static volatile GPIO_Registers* const gpio[]` is in the code below?

and what does the syntax `(volatile GPIO_Registers*)` inside this block do?

```
// GPIO hardware registers
//
typedef struct
{
  uint32_t MODE;
  uint32_t TYPE;
  uint32_t SPEED;
  uint32_t PUSH_PULL;
  uint32_t IDR;
  uint32_t ODR;
  uint32_t BSRR;
  uint32_t LOCK;
  uint32_t ALT_FN1;
  uint32_t ALT_FN2;
} GPIO_Registers;


// Ports can be selected using an enumeration
// (Port) to index into this array.
// Port addresses can be calculated using the enum since
// all ports are at the same offset from each other.
//
static volatile GPIO_Registers* const gpio[] =
{
  (volatile GPIO_Registers*)(GPIO_BASE_ADDR + (PORT_A << 10)),
  (volatile GPIO_Registers*)(GPIO_BASE_ADDR + (PORT_B << 10)),
  (volatile GPIO_Registers*)(GPIO_BASE_ADDR + (PORT_C << 10)),
  (volatile GPIO_Registers*)(GPIO_BASE_ADDR + (PORT_D << 10)),
  (volatile GPIO_Registers*)(GPIO_BASE_ADDR + (PORT_E << 10)),
  (volatile GPIO_Registers*)(GPIO_BASE_ADDR + (PORT_F << 10))
};
```

Comment: What did you figure out yourself? What **specifically** don't you understand in your C book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`static volatile GPIO_Registers* const gpio[]` is a static array of pointer to `GPIO_Registers` variables.

Each element of the array point to a physical address of your `SoC`/`mcu`. So each element points to a physical `GPIO port`. Take a look of your `SoC`/`mcu` datasheet for details. You'll find out that each GPIO port of your SoC has all 32bits registers specified by `GPIO_Registers` struct.

`(volatile GPIO_Registers*)` is a simple type cast that is required due to the fact that `GPIO_BASE_ADDR` and other defines are simple "numbers" and you must specify the type of those "numbers".

Answer (score 0):

`(volatile GPIO_Registers*)(GPIO_BASE_ADDR + (PORT_A << 10))` line tells that the address is a *Structure pointer* and *volatile*. The value at this address may change at any time by the hardware.

`static volatile GPIO_Registers* const gpio[]` line tells that `gpio` is *constant* variable of *Structure pointer* ,*volatile* and *static*. The value at this pointer is constant-volatile and is local to the file itself, not seen by other files in the project, so it is `static`. As variable deals with hardware i.e GPIO, the value may change on the go, so it is `constant` and `volatile`

Comment: "the value may change on the go, so it is constant and [...]" ??

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - value of the pointer, ie, the address  of the GPIO register, does not change.  The target of the pointer, ie, the bits in that register may.  But volatile does not mean that the program can change something, it means that the compiler must actually perform the access, because something else may have, or the act of accessing may have side effects - so while it is not the case here, you can declare something both const and volatile.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I'm aware that. I merely pointed out that the sentence didn't make sense.

Comment: "The value at this pointer is constant-volatile" is indeed a misstatement.

Comment: @Karoly Horvoth can you suggest a statement which make sense there

Answer (score -1):

```
(volatile GPIO_Registers*)(GPIO_BASE_ADDR + (PORT_A << 10))
```

This line in the code casts the address to a `volatile Structure pointer` and the value at this address in this can be changed by the hardware.